# RegEx to modify urls in htmlText as3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, string, formatting

I have some html text that I set into a TextField in flash. I want to highlight links (  either in a different colour, either just by using underline and make sure the link target is set to "_blank".

I am really bad at RegEx. I found a handy expression on [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) :

```
 </?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>
```

but I couldn't use it.

What I will be dealing with is this:

```
<a href="http://randomwebsite.web" />
```

I will need to do a String.replace()

to get something like this:

```
<u><a href="http://randomwebsite.web" target="_blank"/></u>
```

I'm not sure this can be done in one go. Priority is making sure the link has target set to blank.

Comment: have you considered using stylesheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend you this simple test tool
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Here's a working example with a more complex input string.

```
var pattern:RegExp = /<a href="([\w:\/.-_]*)"[ ]* \/>/gi;
var str:String = 'hello world <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" /> hello there';
var newstr = str.replace(pattern, '<li><a href="$1" target="blank" /></li>');
trace(newstr);
```

Comment: that old school split/join action solved the replace problem.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how Action Script regexes work, but noting that attributes can appear anywhere in the tag, you can substitute `<a target="_blank" href=` for every `<a href=`. Something like this maybe:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /<a\s+href=/g;
var str:String = "<a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/\">";
str.replace(pattern, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=");
```

Copied from Adobe docs because I do not know much about AS3 regex syntax.

Now, manipulating HTML through regex is usually very fragile, but I think you can get away with it in this case. First, a better way to style the link would be through CSS, rather than using the `<font>` tag:

```
str.replace(pattern, "<a style=\"color:#00d\" target=\"_blank\" href=");
```

To surround the link with other tags, you have to ***capture*** everything in `<a ...>anchor text</a>` which is fraught with difficulty in the general case, because pretty much anything can go in there.

Another approach would be to use:

```
var start:RegExp = /<a href=/g;
var end:RegExp = /<\/a>/g;
var str:String = "<a\s+href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/\">";
str.replace(start, "<font color=\"#0000dd\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=");  
str.replace(end, "</a></font>");
```

As I said, I have never used AS and so take this with a grain of salt. You might be better off if you have any way of manipulating the DOM.

Something like this might appear to work as well:

```
var pattern:RegExp = /<a\s+href=(.+?)<\/a>/mg;
...
str.replace(pattern, 
    "<font color=\"#0000dd\"><a target=\"_blank\" href=$1</a></font>");
```

Comment: Thanks that solves the biggest issue. A clear case of RTFM for me here. I could easily put a <font color=#0000DD>in front, but any hints on how I can add the closing </font> at the end of the <a /> tag ? Sağol!

Comment: Bir şey değil. That was a nice touch. BTW, I did not mean RTFM. I just had to read them because I have never used AS before.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for the trouble. It's annoying to work with replace because it replaces just the first occurance of the regex, not all of them :(

Answer (score 0):

What about this?  I needed this for myself and it looks for al links (a-tags) with ot without a target already.

```
var pattern:RegExp = /<a (  ( [^>](?!target) )*  ) ((.+)target="[^"]*")*  (.*)<\/a> /xgi;
str.replace(pattern, '<a$1$4 target="_blank"$5<\/a>');
```