# How to extract text using regex in Actionscript?

Tags: regex, apache-flex, actionscript-3

In the HTML below:

```
<a href="link1.php">1</a><a href="link2.php">2</a><a href="link3.php">3</a>
```

How do I extract `link1.php,link2.php,link3.php` and push them into an array using regex? (There could be `N` number of `<a>` tags in the text)

**[Edit]** I'm aware the regex for this is something like `href="([^"])*"`. But I'd like to know how to go about this in Actionscript. Specifically, how can they be pushed into an array **in Actionscript**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str:String = '<a href="link1.php">1</a><a href="link2.php">2</a><a href="link3.php">3</a>';
var result:Array = str.split(/<a[^>]*href="([^"]*)".*?>.*?<\/a>/);
for (var i:int = 1; i < result.length; i += 2) {
    trace(result[i]);  // link1.php, link2.php, link3.php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a[^>]*href="([^"]*)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex `href="([^"])*"` should work most of the time. It'd capture into `\1`. You may have to use this in a loop, and you may have to escape the `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`RegExp.exec()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/RegExp.html#exec%28%29) will return an Object that you can access by index, like an array.

Also, you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342788/regex-to-modify-urls-in-htmltext-as3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748569/how-do-i-replace-all-the-links-in-a-text-using-regex-in-as3) post handy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use [**regex to parse html**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)?

How about something like:

```
var anchors:String = '<a href="link1.php">1</a><a href="link2.php">2</a><a href="link3.php">3</a>';
var html = new XML('<p>' + anchors + '</p>');
var links:Array = [];
for each(var a:XML in html.a)
  links.push(String(a.@href));
```

Comment: **The text might be like this** : <a href="link1.php">1</a> There could be lots of text here<a href="link2.php">2</a> These links are between lots of simple text<a href="link3.php">3</a> So making this an XML may not be a very good idea?

Comment: As long as it is valid xml and all anchor tags are at the top level (not inside another p or div), this will work fine. If anchor tags are nested, you can use `html..a` instead of `html.a` inside `for each` to access all the descendants that are anchors.